# GCP Cloud Build - Buildpack -> gradle -> testcontainers

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, testcontainers, buildpack

having issue by switching to cloud build. Before we were using other platform and just started the grade build. We use spring boot and testcontainers for tests. Now in cloud build the gradle project is going to be built by buildpack. Gradle builds our project and runs tests. These integration tests are failing because testcontainers cannot start required containers. What can be enabled in the cloudbuild.yml to make it possible?

```yaml
steps:
- name: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack
args:
- build
- '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
- '--env'
- 'BP_GRADLE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS=$_GRADLE_ARGS'
- '--tag=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME:$_TAG_2'
- '--builder=paketobuildpacks/builder:base'
- '--path=.'
id: Buildpack
entrypoint: pack
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might I recommend the following [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudbuild-integration-testing) which explains how to perform multi-container integration tests? It is officially from Google, after all (or, well, specifically GCP which is what Cloud Build is a product of). Please let me know if any of it needs explaining or if this isn't what you're referring to (though it seems to be what you're asking considering `testcontainers` is plural and you mention that it's the integration tests that are failing)

Answer (score 2):

To keep this question from being complete unanswered, I recommend that anyone who wishes to perform multi-container integration tests to use the following Github Repository as a reference:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudbuild-integration-testing

And to answer OP's question specifically:
There's no need to enable anything specific in order to test things, but integration testing for containers is best performed by other containers that *wait for* the containers to be built before running tests, as can be seen in this [file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudbuild-integration-testing/blob/master/cloudbuild.compose.yaml)